# How can I use the Error Handler to reconnect to the redistribution server in StackServices.RedisMqServer?

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm using a queue to direct the service error events, but if the redistribution server fails, I need the queue to try to connect itself to the redistribution server, at least 2 more times after the exception is thrown.

I am trying to use the `RetryCount` property, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to try to reconnect to the redistribution server through `ErrorHandler`?

Comment: With Google translator  he says " I'm using a queue to manage events as errors in the service, but if the redis server fails, I need the queue try to connect to server, at least 2 more times after throwing the exception.I'm trying to use the property * RetryCount *, but it seems not work. It's another way to re-attempt to connect to the server via ErrorHandler ?

Comment: This question (as well as the only answer) is not in English

Answer (score 0):

I suppose,   I don't know Spanish, neither I use Redis,
reading only the documentation [ServiceStack RedisMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis#redismqserver)

this is the [initialization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis#example), where you set the retryCount .

```
       var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
       var mqHost = new RedisMqServer(redisFactory, retryCount:2);
```

but the RetryCount, is protected (set)

```
                  public int RetryCount { get; protected set; }
```

So I think it is not possible to reset it.

I don't know  about another way to "re-attempt to connect to the server via ErrorHandler "

I gave it a try

BTW I cannot find the source in github  for RedisMqServer  in  ServiceStack v3.

During the last changes, it seems  the [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Messaging/RedisMqServer.cs)  is broken.